# How to Protect PHP Url From Direct Accessing?

Tags: php, json, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am using a web link eg: http://example.com/abc/abc.php for retrieving JSON Data in my Application eg windows phone.

Everything works fine but the url can be direct accessible from the browser. I don't want the url to be direct accessible.

How to Protect the Url from Direct Access but Allow from the App?

Comment: put the script outside of the directory root?

Comment: You can't 100% prevent this. The app looks exactly like the browser when it is making a request. And if it doesn't, nothing would stop someone from changing their user agent, session, whatever to make it look that way. You could slow people down by setting a header with a token, changing the user agent in the app or posting a token value. Then checking with your php script if this is the expected value. But that can all be spoofed by a browser with little work.

Comment: If it's a POST url, then add a token that must be verified. It won't completely stop access, but it will greatly reduce it.

Comment: If you take the "don't return any data that you rely on your app to hide" strategy, then the point becomes moot.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Yes Token is the Good Way for Protection. But It seems Tricky.  I tried Password Protection for folder but then i access the url with http://username:password@website.com/abc/showall.php but this technique don't work with my app. i think username and password in url are not supported by the app. Any Idea for this. I see some app which are getting request from the urls which are password protected

Answer (score 0):

You can either use something like `.htaccess`**(it's a file that you can use to do url rewriting and redirecting)**, and no . . . I don't know a lot of about that, so you'd have to look up how to do it.

but, if your file is a `php` or `phtml` file, then you could just write:

```
<?php

// just redirect someone away from the file whenever they go to access it.
header("location: your/location/file.php");

?>
```

Anyways, that's about all I can help with, hopefully I was successful as answering this.

Comment: I don't want to redirect any URL I want to Protect my URLs form Direct Browser Access.

Comment: Then, I'm not sure that is quite my field of specialties.